# How insert data in SQL?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

i have 2 sql tables . warehouse with warehouseID and warehouseName; and product table with productID productName and warehouseID. table warehouse always contains only 3 warehouses, but table product can contain up to 250 products, and Im trying write script which will add to table product warehouseID from warehouse table, but one warehouse id can repeats only 50 times, help me please

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @notescrew INSERT INTO product(warehouseID)
SELECT warehouseID FROM warehouse;

Comment: Do you have sample data? What do you mean by repeat only 50? what is the restriction? do you want to make an inventory system or just define warehouses for products.?

Comment: Do you want seed in the Products table? or you want to set a warehouse id depends on the transaction? Please clarify so we can help.

Comment: @U8080 kind sort my products to my warehouse (but 1 warehouse can contain only 50 products)

Comment: How do you want to merge 3 rows from warehouses with 250 rows of products to get single `warehouse_id` for single product?

Comment: The inventory system does not work like this. Is it a flexible project that you can design or it is already an existing database?

Comment: @astentx 250/ 3 not 3/250

Comment: @Babaluka Does it matter? I've placed no role to that numbers, so 3/250 or 250/3 is meaningless. You have some products and want to update some attribute. What is the criteria to define that attribute?

Comment: @U8080 flexible project, just start learn SQL to use it with java

Comment: You should have more reliable designs like a Table for products, a table for warehouses, and finally a table for product transactions that consists of the warehouse. This is the real-life example

Comment: While it is a flexible project, I recommend you learn the right way. I will write you an example as an answer.

Comment: I have added an answer, hope that was helpful for you to learn the basics of inventory systems. Now, you can develop cases and try it, when you have a specific case you stuck in, open a new question so we can help again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The basic requirements** to implement an inventory system is to have three tables at least (four or more is better).

1. The products table – to hold the products information
2. The Warehouses table – to hold the warehouses' information
3. The Transactions table – to hold the In/Out transactions data.
4. The Suppliers table – that deliver us the products
5. The Customers table – that we deliver them the products
6. +Many other parties can make in/out of products.

In this **example** I will go with the minimum which is 3 tables:

To create the tables

```
CREATE TABLE products (p_id int, p_name varchar(200))
CREATE TABLE warehouses (w_id int, w_name varchar(200))
CREATE TABLE warehouse_transactions(wt_id int, wt_date datetime, wt_no int, wt_product_id int, wt_warehouse_id int, wt_qty int, wt_transaction_type varchar(3))
```

To seed products

```
INSERT INTO products VALUES (1, 'ABC KEYBOARD');
INSERT INTO products VALUES (2, 'XYZ KEYBOARD');
INSERT INTO products VALUES (3, 'MMM MONITOR');
```

To seed warehouses

```
INSERT INTO warehouses VALUES (1, 'SE WAREHOUSE')
INSERT INTO warehouses VALUES (2, 'SW WAREHOUSE')
INSERT INTO warehouses VALUES (3, 'N WAREHOUSE')
```

To seed transactions

```
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (1, '2020-11-17',1 , 1, 1, 5, 'IN');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (2, '2020-11-17',2 , 2, 1, 10, 'IN');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (3, '2020-11-17',3 , 2, 1, 3, 'OUT');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (4, '2020-11-17',4 , 3, 2, 6, 'IN');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (5, '2020-11-17',5 , 3, 2, 5, 'OUT');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (6, '2020-11-17',6 , 1, 1, 5, 'IN');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (7, '2020-11-17',7 , 1, 1, 5, 'IN');
INSERT INTO warehouse_transactions VALUES (8, '2020-11-17',8 , 1, 1, 5, 'OUT');
```

To check the current inventory (in general):

```
SELECT
P.p_id AS 'PRODUCT ID'
, P.p_name AS 'PRODUCT NAME'
, W.w_name AS 'WAREHOUSE'
, SUM(CASE WHEN WT.wt_product_id = P.p_id AND WT.wt_transaction_type = 'IN' THEN WT.wt_qty ELSE 0 END) AS 'IN QTY'
, SUM(CASE WHEN WT.wt_product_id = P.p_id AND WT.wt_transaction_type = 'OUT' THEN WT.wt_qty ELSE 0 END) AS 'OUT QTY'
, SUM(CASE WHEN WT.wt_product_id = P.p_id AND WT.wt_transaction_type = 'IN' THEN WT.wt_qty ELSE -1 * WT.wt_qty END) AS 'AVAILABLE'
FROM 
warehouse_transactions WT
INNER JOIN products P ON WT.wt_product_id = P.p_id
INNER JOIN warehouses W ON WT.wt_warehouse_id = W.w_id
GROUP BY P.p_id, P.p_name, W.w_name
```

The results
[image]

To List you Tables Data in general:

```
-- TO LIST ALL PRODUCTS
SELECT * FROM products
-- TO LIST ALL WAREHOUSES
SELECT * FROM warehouses
-- TO LIST ALL TRANSACTIONS
SELECT * FROM warehouse_transactions
```

To delete the table and data (DO IT WHEN YOU NEED ONLY)

```
DROP TABLE products
DROP TABLE warehouses 
DROP TABLE warehouse_transactions
```

***That was an example that may help you to start the journey.***

**The next steps for you could be:**

1. Extend the Products table to include more products' attributes - Same with Warehouses and Transactions
2. Add suppliers and customers tables and include their id in the transaction table.
3. Build new queries to retrieve the inventory between two dates, for a specific product, for a specific warehouse, etc.

.

Comment: When you do inner join on `WT.wt_product_id = P.p_id` there's no need to repeat it in `CASE` expression.

Comment: Thank you @astentx  .You are very right, I just wanted to deliver the basics in an understandable way as the question was from a fresh learner. (i.e wanted to deliver domain solution more than SQL code).